# AWS S3 get object tag for a specific key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Basically i used this AWS_CLI command to set the S3 object key

```
aws s3api  put-object-tagging --bucket <bucket-name> --key <file-name> --tagging '{"TagSet":[{"Key" : "full_name","Value" : "SIVA"}]}'
```

**Question**

How can i get the `value` of the `tag` key ?

If i Provide `key_name` as `full_name`  ==> i want output to be `SIVA`

I know, we need to do something with `get-object-tagging`

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed you can use [get-object-tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-tagging.html). Also can use `--query` and `--output`:

```
aws s3api  get-object-tagging --bucket <bucket-name> --key <file-name> --query "TagSet[?Key=='full_name'].Value" --output text
```

The above will first find tag with `Key` ==  `full_name` in an object, and then it takes its `Value`.